# How can I jump to the next "paragraph"?

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

Right now I'm working with some blocks of text that are over 1000 lines long. Is there a simple way to move to the beginning of the next paragraph?

My workaround for now is searching for two consecutive newline characters:

```
/\n\n
```

Another workaround would be `vip` <kbd>Esc</kbd> `j`

- `vip` **v**isually select **i**n **p**aragraph (which also takes you to the end of the paragraph)
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> Escape from visual selection
- `j` move down

Comment: I think you meant `vap<Esc>j`, right? Too bad there's no 'previous paragraph' equivalent.

Comment: @awvalenti `vap<Esc>j` and `vip<Esc>j` seem to give the same results here. Thanks for pointing out an alternative. Also, `vapo<Esc>kk` will get you two lines before the current paragraph.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, you can use the <kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>{</kbd> paragraph motions to move a paragraph forwards or backwards.

From [`:help paragraph`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#paragraph):

> A paragraph begins after each empty line, and also at each of a set of
>   paragraph macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the `'paragraphs'`
>   option.  The default is `IPLPPPQPP TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp`, which corresponds to
>   the macros `.IP`, `.LP`, etc.  (These are `nroff` macros, so the dot must be in
>   the first column).  A section boundary is also a paragraph boundary.
>   Note that a blank line (only containing white space) is NOT a paragraph
>   boundary.
>   Also note that this does not include a `'{'` or `'}'` in the first column.  When
>   the `'{'` flag is in `'cpoptions'` then `'{'` in the first column is used as a
>   paragraph boundary posix.

Like you would expect, you can of course add a count and/or operator; eg. <kbd>2}</kbd> to move 2 paragraps fowards. Or to delete the previous 2 paragraphs you can use <kbd>3d{</kbd>.

Also see [`:help object-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#object-motions)

Comment: Side note: very useful for programmers is also `[[` and `]]` (as well as `[]` and `][`) to jump between beginning (and end) of functions.

Comment: Unfortunately those function-jumping motions only really work if the opening brace is in the first column. I worked somewhere which put the functions' opening braces at the end of the function declaration line and the suggested tweaks in the docs never worked terribly well. :(

Comment: Very interesting:
"Note that a blank line (only containing white space) is NOT a paragraph boundary."

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms In some vim plugins (namely for VS and VSCode), white space lines are considered paragraph boundaries, which I think is a better behavior since you can't exactly discern them visually otherwise. I wonder if there's a switch somewhere...

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Good question. I was quoting from the help info in MartinTournoij's answer. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939481/215487. "change vim paragraph separator" may be the magic search words in this case