# I can't move around the document while editing

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I am working on a ChromeOS computer with both Vi and Vim.  When I open up the editor to an existing document, I type A to begin editing.  When I try to move around with my arrow keys, the following happens:

[image: vim and vi arrow keys]

I have tried both Vim and Vi, and both of the have this problem. How do I move around in my document while editing it?

Comment: Related (though not an exact duplicate, as this is about vi, not Vim): [Fix arrow keys displaying A, B, C, D in vi (not in vim)](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5123/51).

Comment: In the shell, what is the output of `echo $TERM`? What is the output of `set term` in Vim?

Comment: @muru $TERM is `xterm`, set term is `term=xterm`

Comment: If you don't have `set nocompatible` (i.e. no vimrc) you should have one.

Comment: Use `:set nocomptible` in vim. Also please check the values: `:verbose set cp? cpo?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do need to point out the elephant in the room: **You shouldn't be navigating in insert mode.**

Insert mode is for *inserting* text.  While many implementations of `vi` *allow* you to navigate (using the arrow keys) while in insert mode, the recommended, *normal* method of navigation is to **navigate in normal mode.**  Normal mode should be the mode you are normally in, hence the name.

The topic of modal editing vs. arrow keys is well described (at a beginner level) under "Misconception #1" in [this excellent article](http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html).

As an additional point of background, the terminals upon which `vi` was originally designed didn't even *have* arrow keys.  On some old keyboards the HJKL keys are additionally labelled with arrows; I don't actually know if this came before or after `vi` but I suspect the former.

I highly recommend working your way through the `vimtutor` (on the command line) and reading through the above linked article to start getting a handle on the power of modal editing.  I suspect that the problem of non-functioning arrow keys will drop into total insignificance once you get a feel for the powerful motion commands available in normal mode.  I know I personally *never* use arrow keys while editing text in Vim, and I feel handicapped when using other editors where I must use the arrow keys to navigate.

This site itself will also be of great assistance; for instance, here are a couple posts you may find helpful:

- [How can I jump to the next "paragraph"?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2367/4676)
- [How to disable arrow keys in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5851/4676)  (Ironic, isn't it?)

As to the nitty-gritty of Chrome OS and how it interprets arrow key presses in your terminal, I suspect that debugging it will go beyond the scope of this site.  If you are truly determined to use arrow keys in `vi`, perhaps you will have better luck with the keyboard-to-terminal debugging issue amongst the knowledgeable people over at superuser.com.  Best of luck to you whatever you decide, and I hope you may come to appreciate the power of Vim even with non-arrow-key only usage patterns.  :)

---

P.S.: The most basic motion commands there are, are `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`.  To these you can add `<Space>`, `<Backspace>`, `<Return>` and `-`, and of course the great favorites `w`, `b`, `e` and their whitespace-separated-word counterparts `W`, `B`, `E`.  If you add in sentence motions `(` and `)`, paragraph motions `{` and `}`, searching the word under the cursor forward or backward with `*` and `#` respectively, and same-line character search with `f`, `t`, `F`, `T`, `;` and `,`, and if you actually learn all of those well, or even most of those (which won't take you very long, actually)...I can promise you with total confidence that you will *never* go back to using arrow keys to navigate text within Vim.

This isn't even a complete list of motion commands; far from it.  To see a more complete list along with documentation for each, start Vim, type `:help motion.txt`, and use `j` and `k` as your "down" and "up" keys to scroll through the document.

Comment: "You shouldn't be navigating in insert mode" - > Because pressing the down arrow twice is somehow not as fast as pressing `<Esc>jji`. Never mind that `<Esc>` is also outside the home row, just like the down arrow.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, if a down arrow keystroke could be properly replayed as part of a dot command, I would probably do that sometimes.  Since it can't...I don't bother with arrow keys; `<C-o>2j` is still faster.

Comment: Also, I haven't touched the `<Esc>` key a single time since learning that `<C-[>` does the same thing.

Comment: I've mapped my caps lock key to <kbd>esc</kbd>, it's useful in everything not just vim.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @wildcard's answer is to just edit or create `~/.vimrc` and put the following line in there :

```
set nocompatible
```

Comment: If you have a vimrc at all, `nocompatible` will be automatically set, and setting it yourself has side-effects. For that reason, current advice is to create a vimrc _but not put `:set nocompatible` in it_.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong @D.BenKnoble. I just tested what you said, and creating an empty .vimrc does not fix the issue at all (it would have been very weird). But adding the line in it does.

Comment: This may depend on your version. But see `:help compatible` which definitely states that when a vimrc is present this option is automatically set.

Comment: If it is confirmed that it is not always the case, where's the point of this comment ?

Comment: From [:h 'compatible'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) `When a vimrc or gvimrc file is found while Vim is starting this option is switched off` this is always the case. The issues here are that 1) setting `nocompatible` is not a universal way to fix OP's issue 2) setting 'nocompatible` in your vimrc is useless as the doc says.

Comment: Well, if you're both right , then my eyes are lying to me :) (I have vim 8.0.707) No matter what the docs say, if I create (touch) ~/.vimrc, then the issue is still there, but if I do `echo "set nocompatible" > ~/.vimrc` then it's gone...

Answer (score 0):

First thing I do is
vi ~/.vimrc
echo "set nocompatible" > ~/.vimrc

PS. It is incredible how people ignore the simple fact that vi is totally unusable since decades. It was great in 1980s but not in 2000s (and now is already 2022).

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). I have the impression that your answer is very similar to [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/36803/23502). I would recommend to be careful with opinion in answer they tend to offense and create usefulness debate ;-)